# We have a AWS RDS - SQL Server instance and it is unusably slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a AWS RDS - SQL Server instance and it is unusably slow.

I just ran a simple index create on table with 180k records (small table) and it took ~9 minutes to complete!

create index YearIndex on LiveData(year)

It is also extremely slow in SSMS and Azure Data Studio when viewing the schema (tables/views... )

I'm new to AWS RDS, But I am suspecting there is some connectivity issue problem going on - I can't image this would ever be this slow.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Unlikely to be connectivity since you can send commands to the server. Check the Monitoring graphs and see if anything looks unusual -- particularly the CPU, disk and memory. What instance type are you using? What type and size of disk have you assigned?

Comment: This is a new database in a micro instance. It’s a really small database. And I’m only updating 2 tables. When I try to view the list of tables in SSMS it locks up and doesn’t show them and locks up SSMS. Nothing else is using the database beside me doing the updates. I’ve never seen a database run this slow. So, I’m not sure if this is normal or not. I just upgraded it now and will try again to see if there is any difference.

Comment: By comparison, I have a low tier serverless Azure Sql db for a different application and it runs extremely fast.

Comment: I got handed the instance. So, it's ironic this was downvoted. You would think even the micro tier could handle a connection without locking up. It was 100% unusable even in the smallest use. I was able to get credentials and upgrade them to db.t3.small on the instance and it is working like a normal database now.

Comment: Don't worry too much about downvotes. StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A and some people consider Cloud to be outside this scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the micro tier couldn't handle a connection without locking up. It was 100% unusable even in the smallest use. I was able to get credentials and upgrade to db.t3.small on the instance and it is working like a normal database now.